# How to use AES-CTR with same IV in Python?

Tags: python, encryption

With the pycryptodome library, when encrypting with AES-CTR, the iv keyword argument is unavailable for MODE_CTR. I tried setting nonce to 0, but the second ciphertext is still different from the first ciphertext.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = '1111111111111111'
message = 'Hello, world!'

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=b'0')
ciphertext1 = cipher.encrypt(message)
ciphertext2 = cipher.encrypt(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start afresh with a new instance, so:

```
cipher1 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce='0')
ct_1 = cipher1.encrypt(message)
cipher2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce='0')
ct_2 = cipher2.encrypt(message)
```

Otherwise the offset will have progressed, and that means that you are encrypting with a different part of the generated *key stream*. After more than 16 bytes the counter will have progressed as well, and you are using key stream bits consisting of the next encrypted counter.

Remember that cipher *instances* are stateful. Fortunately they are also pretty lightweight, so re-instantiating a new one is next to harmless.